# Apple app does not work in China

Tags: ios, cordova

Published a cordova app that works fine in Europe and Canada. It's published for android and iOS. Android version works fine in China too. The iOS version is only startable from within the app store in China. The app does not install on the device. App icon is missing. That's what Chinese people report. Also the app seems to be not able to receive data from the API server.

Any explanations for that?

Thanks

Comment: If you followed the news than you might have heard that Apple moved their iCloud service to China for Chinese users recently. Maybe it is related, but in the end we can only guess.

Comment: Know about that. But iCloud is not used by app.

Comment: but maybe in the process of moving to china.

Comment: Maybe. But should not all apps be affected then? Also the app is published Oktober 2017.

Comment: you will have to contact apple if you want more I information not based on guessing. I doubt they will share it with you.

Comment: Done that. Waiting for response.